# Get Thumbnail from a smooth streaming file (.ism)

Tags: c#, wpf, ffmpeg, thumbnails, smooth-streaming

Does any body know how to get a thumbnail/snapshot of a specific frame of a smooth streaming file using C#.net and WPF.

Regards,
Allan

Comment: Why are you guys trying to close my question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here MyPanel is the container where your video is streaming.

```
        var panelPoint = this.MyPanel.PointToScreen(new Point(this.MyPanel.ClientRectangle.X, this.MyPanel.ClientRectangle.Y));
        using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(320, 240))
        {
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(320, Point.Empty, new Size(320, 240));
            }

            if (SimpleIoc.Default.ContainsCreated<ICommonApplicationData>())
            {
                var imageGuidName = Guid.NewGuid();
                fileName = Path.Combine("C:\", "TestFolder", imageGuidName + ".jpg");
                bitmap.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                var tempBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                tempBitmapImage.BeginInit();
                tempBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(fileName);
                tempBitmapImage.EndInit();
                image.Source = tempBitmapImage;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is not a good answer to the question. How can you get an image from a specific frame without going to that frame (without a screenshot).